IS it halal-haram Developing an APP that will be used by military members
Is it Halal or Haram to develop an app that translates or shows the meaning of acronyms across military books? Especially those in the USA with more than 30k words?
This app will be used by military users or members worldwide if not in the USA.. it will make it easier to understand acronyms and terms.

This isn't a fatwa site. Please view: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

If the app will help in defense purpose, then there is no issue. But if it is used by terrorist groups for attack purpose, then I think then you should take care it does not reach their hands.

. And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in
sin and aggression. And fear Allāh; indeed, Allāh is severe in
penalty. Quran 5:2


Please avoid answering questions that are off-topic. This isn't a fatwa site. Also, please make sure to provide reliable references for all your valid on-topic. View, once again, https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

I think it is valid question, we need to address modern issues also. Added reference as requested

It is not a valid question as per site policies. This isn't a fatwa site nor a Muslim peer support site. The objective is to create a library of high-quality academic QNA with references w.r.t. Islam. Our goal here is to not give fatawas, the user is better of using other sites like islamqa.org or islamqa.info or askimam if they are shia for that.

Secondly, your reference is invalid as per the question. It's simply your interpretation. Anyone can interpret any Quranic verse with that much variability without any usul or actual references pertaining to the topic.

first, it is a simple question and mine is a simple answer and not a fatwa. he can decide what he want. For modern problems there is no one eligible for giving fatwa, as it require deep knowledge in all matters both modern and fiqh, which I think no one qualifies

There are Islamic scholars who are academics specialized in the academic knowledge of Islam that requires knowledge of methodologies of jurisprudence and other related subjects to allow one to give fatwa and a certificate that comes alongside passing a test related to it. You, and most of us on this site are clearly not qualified for that job. A layman cannot simply read Quran and Hadith and deduce his own rulings out of his own interpretations without some knowledge in it. Islamic knowledge is not "religious" knowledge per se, but rather an academic subject similar to Maths.

So, in short, what you, and anyone trying to give their own personal opinions and interpretations on a site where it is clearly against the rules to do so is doing is akin to trying to learn linear algebra without calculus. You don't have the prerequisites, it doesn't work. That's why this site has a policy of keeping it simple and straightforward with the QNA. One singular, direct question, that isn't off-topic or seeking personal advice, and one single direct answer that isn't the same as well. Please, once again, read the link I sent. It's not something of my own but official site policy.

I won't reply further but these should be sufficient and you can decide whether you'd like to follow site rules or not: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-a-muslim-peer-support-group

Btw, apologies, askimam is a sunni site not a shia one. Just wanted to mention that.

This app is just like a dictionary but more specifically for the military, just like we do have a medical dictionary.

@Br.GH Please ask your question on islamqa.info, seekersguidance.org, or some other fatwa site based on your denomination of Islam. This site does not have verified qualified professionals to give an answer to your specific scenario and question, which, in reality, is one of the defining factors of a fatwa.
